# Binding v-model from of child component to its parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components

In my parent component I have a simple input as

```
<input v-model="value" />

export default class ParentComponent extends Vue {
  value = "" as string;


async check() {
    try {
       console.log(this.value) // this works, this get the actual value of the input
   …
  }

  }
```

Now I want to create a child component with that input, so I try:

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="inputValue" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: “BaseTextBox",
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And in the parent component:

```
<BaseTextBox v-model="value" />
import BaseTextBox from "@/components/_base/BaseTextBox.vue";
```

The component display correctly, but when I try to access to  this.value in method it display as empty string because did not get modified with `v-model`? How can I bind it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong value "inputValue" in v-model. It would be "value". So your input will take the prop "value" as v-model and modify that directly.

Your child component would be:

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="value" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: “BaseTextBox",
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I tried but I get error  `Unexpected mutation of "value" prop`

Comment: @Jesus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868963/vue-2-mutating-props-vue-warn. There is a solution to that. If you don't like that. You can also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311936/v-model-and-child-components